# How to load all background images at one time

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have first website page and it have few background images, which are crossfading.

So, the problem is that when page are not cached at computer at first, it's took some time to load next background image on crossfading effect.

Any ideas how to load all images at once?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sawqo6j9/

```js
var i=0;
var imghead=[
 "url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-mosaic-background.png)",
 "url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg)",
 "url(http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/gradient-background.jpg)"
 ];

function slideimg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('body').css('background-image', imghead[i]);
        i++;
        if(i==imghead.length) i=0;
        slideimg();
    }, 6000);
}
slideimg();
```

```css
html, body {
     height: 100%;
} 

body {
     background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-mosaic-background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
    -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
    -o-background-size: auto 100%;
     background-size: auto 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in;
     transition: all 2s ease-in;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>There goes page content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the white color that happens after the image?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it gonna shows just for the first time. When all images are loaded, everything is going well.

Comment: This is because initially browser is making 3 calls to load the imgaes from 3 different url. Is it possible to have all these 3 images and create a sprite, then you loop through it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but is it good idea? There is 6 images, they both size are about 3mb and page is responsive - so in different ways, background loads in different positions and etc.

Comment: I will write my approach later on but since you have a span of 6 seconds you could load all your images separately and just hide the others until the time comes for them. I believe such approach would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For caching background images, I usually take the approach to preload them off screen as `<img>` and remove the container they're loaded in when the page has fully loaded :

```
#deposit {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```
$(function() {

var imghead = [
    "//www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-mosaic-background.png",
    "//www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg",
    "//www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/gradient-background.jpg"
    ];

$.each(imghead, function() {

    $('#deposit').append('<img src="' + this + '" alt="">');
});

$(window).on('load', function() {

    $('#deposit').remove();
});
});
```

The `#deposit` element could either be placed inside the markup or added dynamically :

```
$('body').append('<div id="deposit"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define them in preload containers in your CSS.

```
#preload-01 { background: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-mosaic-background.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-02 { background: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg") no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-03 { background: url("http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/gradient-background.jpg") no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

And just add them to your HTML.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sawqo6j9/4/)**

UPDATE: You could add them as images and remove them once they are loaded, via a `.load()` function.

```
var i=0;
var imghead=[
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-mosaic-background.png",
    "http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg",
    "http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/gradient-background.jpg"
];

$(imghead).each(function(key,val){
    $('body').append('<img class="preloader" src="'+val+'">');
    $('.preloader').load(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});

function slideimg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('body').css('background-image', 'url('+imghead[i]+')');
        i++;
        if(i==imghead.length) i=0;
        slideimg();
    }, 6000);
}
slideimg();
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sawqo6j9/10/)**

Comment: Thanks, this solution is good, but maybe there is some way do that with javascript and doesn't create additional containers.