# There is white flash at the start of hover?

Tags: jquery

I have this for an hover effect. it actually works, but theres a blank image between two images when it swaps.

what is wrong with the code below???

```
<img src="/data/images/myimages02.jpg" border="0" class="className"> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".className").mouseover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut(0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', '/data/images/myimage01.jpg');
        }).fadeIn(0);
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut(0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', '/data/images/myimages02.jpg');
        }).fadeIn(0);
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: ThiefMaster, I would make a comment here but I couldn't as my reputation was below 50, you should know that boss. Anyway here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lajon/L6wt1gjo/    scaptain - can you explain what is the issue exactly?

Comment: there is white flash at the start of hover...

Comment: I don't see it but it's likely a cache issue - preload the second image.

Comment: Works for regular images as well : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33479104/3168107.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by pre-loading another image.

Combine two images into one and then on hover just change the background-position CSS property to show different state.

Check out this sample image: http://funkcje.net/images/przycisk2.gif